# Как очистить QBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

Есть вот такой код в tkinter

```
lis_del_ff = self.top_ff.pack_slaves()
for l in lis_del_ff:
l.destroy()
```

Как реализовать подобное на pyqt5? Ясно что отдельный виджет можно удалить

```
box.removeWidget(widget)
```

но как автоматизировать задачу подобно tkinter, если в конкретный момент неизвестно, что за виджеты в боксе?

В итоге я получил вот такой работоспособный код аналогичный tkinter-му:

```
for i in reversed(range(box.count())):
w = box.itemAt(i).widget()
w.setParent(None)
w.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать в `PyQt5` , и что у вас не получается. Приведите пример, который у вас есть (`PyQt5`).

Comment: собственно в ответе ниже есть попытка написать желаемый  мне код, но он не рабочий, по задаче мне нужен список виджетов из бокса, которые я хочу удалить, тем самым очистив бокс

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста то сто у вас есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `QBoxLayout` есть метод `children`, который возвращает список всех виджетов. Остается только пройтись циклом по ним:

```
for i in box.children():
    box.removeWidget(i)
```

```
for i in reversed(range(layout.count())): 
    layout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
```

Comment: не работает, children возвращает только объекты класса QLayout, остальных виджетов не видит и соответственно метод removeWidget не работает

Comment: @Zmiter А так ?

Comment: так в принципе работате, но в данном варианте я так понимаю объект виджета не удаляется, а просто убирается ссылка на родительский элемент. reversed из за "стэкового" характера наполнения бокса?

Answer (score 0):

Да просто удали сам бокс и создай новый. Детей удалит сборщик мусора, если ничего лишнего там не сделано чтоб это предотвратить.

Comment: не работает, бокс удаляется а детки остаются под наехавшим на них следующим боксом с его детками